# Unity inspector can't edit public array's values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a script that has a public array so that I can modify the values in the inspector. Here's an example script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int[] bars;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

When I add the script to a game object, I can see the empty list in the inspector (as expected).

[image]

But when I add elements to the array, the array area is just blank so I can't set the value of each element (or see what the element values are).

[image]

Is this just a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm running Unity 2021.2.5f1 on macOS Monterey 12.0.1.

Comment: I would try compiling the project. Also I would try initializing the array in the code `public int[] bars = new int[1];` although it should work without inizialization I believe

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I changed `public int[] bars;` to `public int[] bars = new int[1];`, recompiled, and removed and re-added the script to the game object, but I'm still having the same issue (although now the inspector shows the array has one value, as expected).

Comment: in case its of any help I checked in Unity 2020.3.11f1 (64-bit) version and your script works fine without initializing the array at all. Values can be added in the inspector, and the integer fields appear and their value can be set...

Comment: Yes as @rustyBucketBay say, its working o my windows 10 PC too with 2020.3.22f1, this might be related with Unity 2021.2.5f1

Comment: Yes that is definitely a bug. Might be related to [this one](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/propertyfield-list-elements-disappear-when-the-window-is-displayed-on-the-second-screen)(?) .. it is definitely working as expected on Windows and in other Unity versions ..

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem after upgrading to a new version of Unity, and I discovered that it works if I move the editor window over to a different screen. Maybe because my main screen is widescreen? I dunno, I can't explain it. If I move the editor back to my main screen, they disappear again. So for now, I just adjust the values on my smaller side-screen, then move back when I'm done. If you don't have more than one screen, perhaps try to change the resolution or something.

Answer (score -1):

May be not the best solution but, definin your own serializable int struct may works.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public struct MyInt
{
    public int Int;
}

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
     public MyInt[] bars;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue for me.